# windows-Install Linux in dualboot and "break" the RAID 0

Tags: linux, windows, debian

I want to install Debian in dualboot with windows, I have two hard drive of 500gb and I want to install Debian on one of them, but they are in RAID 0 under Windows. When I try to install Debian on one of my hard drive, it say me that it will break the RAID, I wanted to know if it is safe to break the raid like that or not ? If it is not, how can I break the raid ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is not safe to use the Debian install process to break the RAID 0. You will lose your existing Windows installation and data.  This is because your data is distributed across the two disks to improve performance. Even if there is less than 500Gb of existing Windows installation and data the RAID 0 configuration requires both disks.

There are many ways that you could proceed.  But first, ask yourself if you really require dual-boot. It could be that you could install VirtualBox and use that for your Debian installation.  This is less work and lower risk and leaves the current configuration intact.  Performance may be close to that you would get with dual boot and you don't have down-time whilst rebooting into the other OS.

My second option would be to put another disk into the machine (or have as external drive) and dual boot from that, leaving the Windows installation in place.  An external disk might run Debian a bit slowly, depending on how it is connected.

My third option would be to create (at least two) complete backups of the machine and then create a fresh installation of Windows onto just one of the existing 500 Gb disks - breaking the RAID 0 during the installation process with Windows.  Then re-install my applications and restore my data into that new Windows environment.  Then install Debian onto the second disk - since Linux installation tools tend to be better for creating dual boot.  This gives you the benefit of a freshly installed Windows system, but does mean lots of re-installation of software.  And you would lose the existing Windows settings.

My fourth option, if I wanted to retain the existing Windows system settings, applications and data would be to create multiple backups of key data and also a bootable copy of the existing setup on a single (new) disk.  The new disk becomes the main Windows system disk and then one (or both) of the existing disks can be used for Debian and data.

Options 2, 3 and 4 require more disks and these might not fit physically into your machine.

Creating and testing the backups and re-installing may take a long time and there is a risk that something will go wrong.

This is not a programming question :)

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer, I will create a backup I think and reinstall windows :)
I thought i could ask my question over Linux too ^^